Geometry still set as point when creating lines in QGIS Geometry Generator
I'm using QGIS to analyze coastal erosion and have come across an issue with geometry type. I have a vector layer of about 150 control points along the shoreline and used a geometry generator to create lines with the bearings used when they are measured in-field.
I wish to find the points where they intersect the shoreline, of which I already have a MultiLineString layer. However, while the geometry generator created visible lines (and are set to be Lines/MultiLineString ), the layer still appears as point geometry when you hover over it in the "layers" tab.
It does not show up when I try to use the vector analysis tool "line intersections". Am I doing something wrong? I'm self-taught in QGIS so it wouldn't surprise me if this has a simple solution, however after scouring the internet, I still cannot find help.

Geometry generator is for display only. You can use the same expression in the geometry by expression to create a new layer. See this post for a detailed comparison of the two.
